# Davening along with the chazan for tefillah bi'tzibbur

Tags: tefilla, tefillah-betzibbur, chazarat-hashatz

There is a concept discussed in halacha that says something about a person who davens along with the chazan or at the same time as the chazan has a status equal to (or almost equal to ) davening with the minyan. Does that mean that the individual has to daven word for word with the chazan or to be in the same bracha at least? Or is it enough to just be davening Shemonah Esrei at the same time as the chazan?

Comment: `There is a concept discussed in halacha that says` could you cite a source about this?

Answer (score 3):

See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim [109, 2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%98_%D7%91).

> If one starts the Tefila at the same time as the Shaliach Tsibbur, when the Shaliach tsibur begins Nakdishach {nekadesh for Ashkenazi minhag, Magen Avraham} one needs to say each word of the whole kedusha as the shaliach tsibur says it and the whole beracha "Hakel Hakkadosh" {with the nusach ledor vador for ashkenazi tsibur, Magen Avraham}, the beracha "Shome'a Tefila", and he should also be sure to bow for "modim" at the same time as the Shaliach Tsibur bows for "Modim" or "Hatov Shimcha Ulecha Na'e Lehodot".

The Ram"a adds that it's better to wait until after the kedusha to start the Tefila. And the M'chaber's din of synchronizing is, according to the Ram"a, only if there is a reason to start with the Shaliach tsibur, or to end tefila on time, or to say tefila immediately after "ge'ula".

One can say the last berachot alone, independently from the Shaliach Tsibbur (Mishna Berura). **The Aruch Hashulchan, se'if 11, says that he needs to say the whole tefila with the Shaliach Tsibur to fulfill the mitsva as if he answered  "Amen" after each beracha**. (the Kitsur Shulchan Aruch siman 69, paragraph 7 also mentions that he needs to say the whole tefila with the Shaliach Tsibur, word for word.)